# django not giving me the file even though it the link is directed to the file

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to download a file when a link is clicked. The link is generated dynamically using javascript when the file has been created. In my template the function that adds the links looks like:

```
function Download(desiredLink) {
            var a = $('<a />');
            a.attr('download',desiredLink);
            desiredLink = {{MEDIA_URL}}  +desiredLink+'.docx';
            a.attr('href',desiredLink);
            a.text("Download");
            $('body').append(a);
        };
```

I have specified the MEDIA_URL in my settings.py file like:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'documents/')
MEDIA_URL = '/documents/'
```

The link generated has the correct url when I inspect it. But when I click the button it tries to download the file but says `Failed-No file`. Any solution would be appreciated. The generated link looks like: `localhost:8000/documents/test.docx`. And the files are found in the documents folder which is found in the root folder of the project.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411175/how-to-fix-failed-no-file-on-download

Comment: @Phanti are you suggesting I turn my files into .txt?

Comment: What's the generated URL and where the file actually lies in the filesystem?

Comment: @heemayl I have made an edit specifying the URL and the location of the file

Comment: Okay. So e.g. a file reside in `<BASE_DIR>/documents/file` and the URL is `/documents/file`?

Comment: @heemayl No it says localhost:8000/documents/file

Comment: Drop the hostname, otherwise it's like I mentioned?

Comment: @heemayl yes it is

Comment: Did you add the media URL to URLConf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202093/discussion-between-abdulaziz-yesuf-and-heemayl).

Comment: @heemayl No I just specified it in the settings.py